# Installing Latex on Virtualenv

Tags: software-installation, python, latex, virtualenv

I'm trying to install latex on virtualenv as a part of my project being uploaded to heroku.  I used `pip install texlive-latex-extra` also `easy_install texlive-latex-extra` for packages `texlive-base`,`texlive-latex`, `texlive`, `texlive-latex-extra` as I've mentioned etc. It's giving me a message that packages don't exist, although I have installed them locally:

```
Searching for texlive-latex
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/texlive-latex/
Couldn't find index page for 'texlive-latex' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for texlive-latex
```

What point am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are confusing two different concepts. `pip` is a tool to install python packages (on your current system or in a virtualenv) that you can use with the `python` interpreter.

The packages you are referring are not python packages but binary packages (packages that provide programs and libraries specific to Ubuntu system), and can only be installed in your system (using `apt-get` or a similar tool).

So, you cannot install LaTeX in a virtualenv (although eventually you could find some package in pip that provides bindings to use LaTeX with python).

Comment: On ubuntu, the base package is `texlive-latex-base`, I also needed `texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended`. `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended`